# MYSQL Select based on date, then join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one table has a list events with various details of an event. I have a second table with tickets and specific ticket information (seat number, section number, price, etc) that link to the event.

Obviously an event may have several tickets.

What I would like to do is `JOIN` the `events` table with the `tickets` table `BY` the `events_id` (the primary key of the events table and there is a column in the tickets table for `events_id`). But I need to take it one step further. Currently I can do this to join the events and the tickets.

```
SELECT * FROM events e INNER JOIN tickets t ON e.id = t.events_id;
```

This works. But I need to take it one step further. I don't want to join all of the events. I only want the events for today and then join those events.

I have been able to successfully get todays events (without joining) with this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE `date` = CURDATE();
```

But I want to be able to combine these two queries into one query. I want to first grab all of today's events, and then I want to `JOIN` the `tickets` table to todays events based on the `events_id` foreign key.

I have tried and tried, many different things without any success. This can not be the first time someone has needed to do something like this. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL Server?

Comment: StackOverflow suggested it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do

```
SELECT * FROM events e 
INNER JOIN tickets t ON e.id = t.events_id
where e.`date` = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Such a simple solution. For some reason I was taught that you can't use the `WHERE` clause in a `JOIN` query. Well it helps a lot to know that I can actually do this now. Thank!

Comment: @jacurtis . . . You can *definitely* use a `where` clause in a `join` query.  However, you want the *join* conditions to go in an `on` clause.  The `where` clause should be for filtering.

Comment: @jacurtis yes you can use where condition on JOIN queries but make sure that there are no ambiguous columns i.e. the same column names in both the tables and if yes use them using the alias in the where condition. For example if date is there in both the table and you use where date = CURDATE() it will return error, but specifying e.`date` we are telling the query to match the date value in event table :)